# How can I transfer my Xbox slim files to my other xbox slim

Tags: xbox-360

Basically my xbox broke, so I used my brothers for a long time, but now mine is fixed pretty much nothing is on it. I tried putting them on a memory card but it made me format it and after I did that it still wouldn't let me, and it also wouldn't let me put anything on :(

Comment: What errors did it give you when it "didn't let you" put stuff on the formatted card? When you say you formatted it, do you mean that you let the Xbox format it, or did you take it out and format it in a computer? What size of memory card is it? What size of files are you trying to put on it?

Answer (score -1):

Try to save it in a formatted usb or save in the Hard Disk, then copy them on your xbox. Delete them after you've copied before returning the usb/hd, if you want.